# how to get dynamically added control values from form to arraylist in the form of bean, xml configuration without annotations in spring 2.x?

Tags: spring, dynamic, arraylist, controls, javabeans

Getting dynamically added control values from form to Controller on spring2.x without using annotations using only xml configuration?

Here is my sample code..

```
// customer.jsp

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<html>
<head>
 <script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //add more file components if Add is clicked
    $('#addButton').click(function() {
        var index = $('#TextBoxesGroup tr').children().length - 1;
        $('#TextBoxesGroup').append(
                '<tr><td>'+
                '   <input type="text" name="pid['+ index +']" />'+
                '</td><td>'+
                '   <input type="text" name="quantity['+ index +']" />'+
                '</td><td>'+
                '   <input type="text" name="productPrice['+ index +']" />'+
                '</td><td>'+
                '   <input type="text" name="total['+ index +']" />'+
                '</td></tr>');
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

 <form:form commandName="customerForm" method="post" name="customerForm" >  
 <table >
<tr>
<td>Customer Address</td>
<td><form:input path="customerAddress"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Invoice</td><td><input type="file" name="invoice"/></td></tr> 

</table> 
<hr/>
<table id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <tr><th>PID</th><th>PRICE</th></tr>
    <tr id="TextBoxDiv1" >
        <td><input type="text" id="pid[0]" name="pid[0]"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text"  id="quantity[0]" name="quantity[0]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text"  id="productPrice[0]" name="productPrice[0]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text"  id="total1" name="total[0]" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton' > 
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>


 </form:form> 

</body>
</html>
```

I tried by storing Customer bean object in ArrayList of CustomerForm.I did not get values. I got NullPointerException. How to resolve it?

```
//CustomerForm.java


package info;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.commons.collections.functors.InstantiateFactory;
import org.apache.commons.collections.list.LazyList;

public class CustomerForm {

    private String customerAddress;
    private String invoice;
    private List<Customer> list=new ArrayList<Customer>();
    private byte b[];
    private String edit;
    private String delete;
    private Integer aid;

    //Setters and getters
}   

//Customer.java

package info;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Blob;

public class Customer {

    private Integer pid;
    private Integer quantity;
    private Double productPrice;
    private Double total;
    //Setters and getters
}
```